JazzCash Sandbox Environment: Transaction Failed with Response Code 199
I am testing the JazzCash sandbox environment for processing payments in my Laravel application, but I am encountering an issue. The transaction fails, returning the response code 199 with the message:

Sorry! Your transaction was not successful. Please try again later.

Below is the JSON request being sent to the JazzCash server:
 {
      "pp_Version": "1.1",
      "pp_TxnType": "MWALLET",
      "pp_Language": "EN",
      "pp_MerchantID": "my_marchant_id",
      "pp_SubMerchantID": null,
      "pp_UsageMode": "PR",
      "pp_Password": "my_password",
      "pp_BankID": "",
      "pp_ProductID": "",
      "pp_TxnRefNo": "T17355384763161",
      "pp_Amount": "30000",
      "pp_DiscountedAmount": "",
      "pp_TxnCurrency": "PKR",
      "pp_TxnDateTime": "20241230060116",
      "pp_BillReference": "bill1234",
      "pp_Description": "Description of transaction",
      "pp_TxnExpiryDateTime": "20250228060116",
      "pp_ReturnURL": "https://ethical-emu-helpful.ngrok-free.app/payment/response",
      "pp_SecureHash": "524B68C6CA8E0974D1278CBE18F29F4C0DFD00B62548A7D1FE4F1379629654A0",
      "ppmpf_1": "Ejaz Hussain",
      "ppmpf_2": "syedmushahidhussain456@gmail.com",
      "ppmpf_3": "2",
      "ppmpf_4": "",
      "ppmpf_5": "",
      "pp_MobileNumber": "03123456789",
      "DiscountProfileId": null,
      "ppTxnOrderIdentifier": null,
      "pp_PaymentInstrumentNumber": "03123456789",
      "pp_PaymentInstrumentID": "0"
    }

Here is the JSON response received:
{
  "pp_Amount": "30000",
  "pp_AuthCode": "",
  "pp_BankID": "",
  "pp_BillReference": "bill1234",
  "pp_Language": "EN",
  "pp_MerchantID": "my_marchant_id",
  "pp_ResponseCode": "199",
  "pp_ResponseMessage": "Sorry! Your transaction was not successful. Please try again later.",
  "pp_RetreivalReferenceNo": "241230819056",
  "pp_SecureHash": "8710B300223B52F0EF2659418AECBD143F08799B9C2A5C581F6DB0D508A330A8",
  "pp_SettlementExpiry": "",
  "pp_SubMerchantId": "",
  "pp_TxnCurrency": "PKR",
  "pp_TxnDateTime": "20241230060116",
  "pp_TxnRefNo": "T17355384763161",
  "pp_TxnType": "MWALLET",
  "pp_Version": "1.1",
  "ppmpf_1": "Ejaz Hussain",
  "ppmpf_2": "syedmushahidhussain456@gmail.com",
  "ppmpf_3": "2",
  "ppmpf_4": "",
  "ppmpf_5": ""
}

What I've tried:

Verified that all required fields are correctly formatted and filled.
Ensured that the pp_SecureHash is generated using the correct algorithm and matches the expected format.
Confirmed that the sandbox credentials provided by JazzCash are correct.
Checked the pp_ReturnURL to make sure it is accessible (using Ngrok).

Questions:

What does the response code 199 signify in the JazzCash sandbox environment?

Could there be an issue with my sandbox credentials or environment setup?

How can I resolve this to successfully test the transaction in the sandbox?


